# 'resourceGroupName' does not match expected pattern '^[-\w\._\(\)]+$'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

Working with GitHub project AzViz. I am attempting to run a PowerShell command to pull from a CSV file a list of multiple resource groups. It appears to pull in the groups but errors out with the following:

```
Get-AzResourceGroup : 'resourceGroupName' does not match expected pattern '^[-\w\._\(\)]+$'.
```

I am creating the function here:

```
$rsglist = Import-Csv C:\temp\azureinventory.csv
```

And running the following command:

```
Export-AzViz -ResourceGroup $rsglist -Theme dark -OutputFormat png -Show
```

You can see in this image that it is seemingly importing those resource groups:

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

I suspect its telling me one of the group names is wrong, but going through all of the names, I don't see any not matching that pattern; I don't see any characters that would not be allowed.

I also understand this is a project and there may be issues within their code, just looking for any assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Export-AzViz`'s `-ResourceGroup` parameter expects an array of *strings*, whereas you're passing `[pscustomobject]` instances (which turn into unhelpful string representations), as output by [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv).

Use the appropriate column (property) name from your CSV file to only pass the resource-group *names*, as strings; e.g., if the name information is in the `Name` column:

```sh
Export-AzViz -ResourceGroup $rsglist.Name -Theme dark -OutputFormat png -Show
```

<sup>Note: Accessing the `.Name` property on the *collection* (array) of objects stored in `$rsglist` in order to get the `.Name` property values of the *elements* of that collection is a convenient PowerShell feature called [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).</sup>

Comment: My pleasure, @rmittlerRenPSG. Re removing the header from a CSV file that contains only 1 column in order to read just _values_: You then don't need `Import-Csv` and can read the file with `Get-Content`.